# Unexpected top level exception in android studio.I have done all the required things

Tags: android

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0'
}
```

I have added google play service once in gradle although this error comes. I check everyting but not detecing anything. So please give me direction to resolve this. I am working On a Project in which i have to use Google Cloud Messaging Service that's why i have installed and added the google-play-service in dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Android Studio?

Comment: can you include the log?

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'

Comment: @Lalit :Try above .I hope it will helps you

Comment: yes i restart android studio,included the log and added the compile''statement in dependencies which i shown above in my question.

Comment: I also done suggestion given by Intelli J Amiya but nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

Check it: Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Tools
[image: Check it]